# Invite people liked on post to like fanpage effectiveness measurement

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, facebook-insights

I am going to find out the Like source of Facebook Page I am managing.

My page is much less than 100K page likes. I would like to use the invite function for those users given reactions towards posts, but did not like my page. (Similar steps in impactiv8.com.au/invite-people-who-like-your-facebook-post-to-like-your-page/)

**Main Question: Now I would like to find out how is this effectiveness.
Which parameter(s) provided by Facebook I should have a look?**

**Second  Question: Is it possible somebody likes my page after my invitation, but that like source counted as "Page profile" type?**

I tried Facebook Insights export data and the Graph API, but I am confused.

## 1) Facebook Insights data Export

The Export xls file both "Daily Like Source" are selected.

The descriptions are:
"Daily: This is a breakdown of the number of Page likes from the most common places where people can like your Page. (Total Count)"
"Daily: The number of people who liked your Page, broken down by the most common places where people can like your Page. (Unique Users)"

The fields given are as the following:

- ads
- api
- banhammer
- comment_chaining
- engagement_pyml
- external_connect
- feed_chaining
- feed_pyml
- feed_story
- hovercard
- launch_point_discover_pyml
- like_story
- live_video
- mobile
- mobile_ads
- mobile_page_browser
- mobile_page_suggestions_on_liking
- outbound_click_chaining
- page_browser
- page_browser_invite
- page_contextual_recommendations
- page_finch_related_pages
- page_invite
- page_invite_escape_hatch_finch
- page_profile
- page_timeline
- pagelike_adder_for_reactivated_users
- profile_edit
- reminder_box_invite
- search
- sponsored_story
- timeline_collection
- timeline_like_chaining
- unknown
- vertex_page
- wap

## 2) Graph API (v2.9)

I also tried Graph API described in
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/insights
I suspect **"page_suggestion"** under "page_fans_by_like_source" described in the docs looks like what I want.

However, I cannot find it in the JSON output in the Graph API Explorer.

Also, this post(www.sotrender.com/blog/2017/04/page-like-sources-facebook/) introduced something like "PYML suggestion". I find PYML in the JSON, but none description in docs.

The fields given are as the following:

- end_time(* only appear at Graph API, not Insights data Export)
- ads
- api
- banhammer
- comment_chaining
- engagement_pyml
- external_connect
- feed_chaining
- feed_pyml
- feed_share_link (* only appear at Graph API, not Insights data Export)
- feed_story
- hovercard
- launch_point_discover_pyml
- like_story
- live_video
- mobile
- mobile_ads
- mobile_page_browser
- mobile_page_suggestions_on_liking
- outbound_click_chaining
- page_browser
- page_browser_invite
- page_contextual_recommendations
- page_finch_related_pages
- page_invite
- page_invite_escape_hatch_finch
- page_profile
- page_timeline
- pagelike_adder_for_reactivated_users
- photo_snowlift (* only appear at Graph API, not Insights data Export)
- profile_edit
- reminder_box_invite
- search
- sponsored_story
- timeline_collection
- timeline_like_chaining
- unknown
- vertex_page
- wap

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you want things that this extension does: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-fan-inviter-cust/nadkillaoaocaambipdgoookeaghjeik ? Why not use it?

Comment: Thank for your reply. Actually, I would like to see how much people like my page after invitation sent. One can invite all people who likes by the tools you mentioned, but the timing of sending invitation is still needed to test. So I want some measurement of this conversion rate.